# Do I need to redraw my control on the consumer form if I have updated it?

Tags: c#, windows

there is a user control on my Application.(App1)
now I have made some changes to the project of that user control.(App2)
the exe,dll,etc of all these projects all are on the same folder and of course App1 has a refrence to App2.

should I delete the user control on my Application1 and drop it on it again with the user control that has the latest changes Or because it gets the latest control because it is being referenced by App1?

Comment: It should update _if_ you have the right referencing structure setup. Your text does not make that clear. Dropping it (on a temp form) might help to establish which version is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to remove the `UserControl` and re-add it, but you do need to **rebuild** it after you change it before the changes will "take effect" in the designer.  In fact you will get a warning in the *Error List* saying as much:

> Warning: You must rebuild your project for the changes to WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.UserControl1 to show up in any open designers.

any time you make changes to the `UserControl`.

If you switch to the designer of the `Form` that is using the `UserControl` and press `Ctrl+Shift+B` to build the solution, you will see the designer visibly refresh and your recent changes will be applied.